# ActionFilter to read Contents before RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I wish to record deletes and edits, and thought the best way would be to apply An actionFilter
Attribute to my delete and edit [ post ]  methods

But because the end results is a redirect to action,  my Context.Result is always null
because there is only a Context.RedirectToAction results available.

Now before i go creating some code to plug into my delete and Edit functions, has anyone tried something like this!, and could you possibly advise?

Thanks

Action Code:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
    [SiteChangeLogger(LogType = "Update", TableName = "Affiliates")]
    public ActionResult Edit(Affiliate affiliate, FormCollection form)
    {
        var existing = db2.Affiliates.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AffiliateId == affiliate.AffiliateId);
        ViewBag.before = Common.Strings.Base64Encode(Common.Strings.ToJsonString(existing));
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var curFiles = new NameValueCollection();
                curFiles["AffiliateLogo"] = affiliate.AffiliateLogo;
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(form["AffiliateLogo"]))
                {
                     UploadFiles(form,curFiles);
                     TryUpdateModel(affiliate, form);

                     var oldFileName = affiliate.AffiliateLogo;
                     var newFileName = Common.Strings.RandomFileName();
                     new WebImage(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/" + affiliate.AffiliateLogo))
                         .Resize(200, 50, true, true)
                         .Crop(1, 1)
                         .Save(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/" + newFileName), "png", true);
                     affiliate.AffiliateLogo = newFileName + ".png";
                     Common.Common.TryAndDeleteFile("~/Content/images/" + oldFileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    affiliate.AffiliateLogo = existing.AffiliateLogo;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Common.Common.CompileErrorMessage(ex,"ADMIN.Affiliate.Edit");
            }
            finally
            {
                db.Entry(affiliate).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();   
            }
            ViewBag.after = Common.Strings.Base64Encode(Common.Strings.ToJsonString(affiliate));
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(affiliate);
    }
```

my Filter Code

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext fc)
    {
        var viewResult = fc.Result as ViewResult;

        if(viewResult == null) return;

        var beforeData = viewResult.ViewBag.before;
        var afterData = viewResult.ViewBag.after;

        if (beforeData == null && afterData == null) return;

        var ctx = new SgeGamesContext();
        var eventId = 0;
        var siteChangeLogEvent = ctx.SiteChangeLogEvents.SingleOrDefault(x => x.SiteChangeLogEventName == LogType);
        if (siteChangeLogEvent != null)
        {
            eventId = siteChangeLogEvent.SiteChangeLogEventId;
        }

        var model = new Sge.Games.Data.Models.SiteChangeLog
                        {
                            SiteChangeLogTable = TableName,
                            SiteId = 1,
                            SiteChangeLogAfterContent = afterData,
                            SiteChangeLogBeforeContent = beforeData,
                            SiteChangeLogEventId = eventId
                        };
        ctx.SiteChangeLogs.Add(model);
        ctx.SaveChanges();

        base.OnResultExecuted(fc);
    }
```

Comment: You should show your code, what have you tried?

Comment: code does not apply its empty, create the code yourself and you can see its empty in the debugger, its a behaviour thing and i dont run MVC from source.

Comment: you can also view the code here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking and what the problem is. Could you provide an example of how an Edit action might look like and exactly what information you are trying to fetch in the custom action filter?

Comment: HI Darin.    in my actions i am setting ViewBag.Before(model before change)  and a ViewBag.After(new updated model), now i thought i could simply do a OnActionExecuted and make a log of what user and what data was deleted or edited. but because its a redirect, there is no fc.Result as ViewResult;  because its a redirectResult not a ViewResult, so would ideally need a workaround, have been thinking of population an empty ViewBag on starting, and seeing if its available that way ????

Comment: But why do you need a ViewResult if you redirect? There's no model. What's the point of storing something into ViewBag if you are going to redirect? This doesn't make any sense. ViewBag is used when you want to pass some information to the corresponding view that your controller action is going to render. Inside the custom action filter you could access the ViewBag.

Comment: Thanks, and yes i know the reason for ViewBag, i dont want to return a View, I am also aware of this.   What i want is a filter to log my changes that i can change all the code for ( if needed ) without having to change all the code that uses it.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access the ViewBag directly, you don't need a ViewResult:

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext fc)
{
    var before = fc.Controller.ViewBag.before;
    var after = fc.Controller.ViewBag.after;
    ...
}
```

Also you probably want to use the `OnActionExecuted` event instead of `OnResultExecuted`.

Comment: Thanks Darin, that's it, I knew there was something :-))   thanks very much